# How can I add a variables to my page.html.twig file?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I'm trying to add a variable that i can use in page.html.twig that will add a class to the header region if a field in the node exists.

In template_preprocess_page() i've tried doing the following and have not been able to add a variable:

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  $variables['header_attributes']['class'] = [];
  $variables['header_attributes']['class'] = array_merge($variables['header_attributes']['class'], ['myClassHere']);
}
```

I based this off the example for [menu preprocess](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/modifying-attributes-in-a-theme-file) but no new class was added to the  ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no index called `header_attributes` inside `$variables` array no need to create it, there is `page` index just use it:
Try this out:

```
function [yourThemeName|yourModuleName]_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  $variables['page']['header_attributes']['class']= 'myClassHere';
}
```

**Note** don't forget to clear cache.
In your twig you will get your class by:

```
page['header_attributes']['class']
```

Comment: to implement template_preprocess_page(), in the function name theme_preprocess_page(), replace 'theme' with the name of your custom theme. 
Implement it in your theme's .theme file.
Then clear cache